# Form Data Not Posting While Using URL Rewrite

Tags: asp.net, forms, url-rewriting, asp-classic, web-config

OK. Where to start....

I have a website. It is running on an IIS server using classic asp. I have forms on that website.

The forms were working fine until I decided to add some url rewrite rules to my web.config file to redirect nice looking urls. 
After doing that, the form on my website does not post the data. It is going to the correct address, but nothing is passing to the page that is suppose to do the processing. On the page that I am processing if I do this:

```
For each FieldName in Request.Form
Response.write FieldName & " = " & Request.Form(FieldName) & "<br>" 
Next
```

I get absolutely nothing. No form field names or values.

What do I need to add to the web.config file so that the data will post? And... more importantly... Where do I need to add it at in my web.config file?

Here is a text copy of my web.config file http://elvis-is-alive.com/webconfig.txt

Comment: BTW.... here is a link to the form http://elvis-is-alive.com/sign-guestbook I am posting a link rather than the code so you can see the entire thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your web.config contains `action=redirect`.

A redirect always results redirect header being sent to the browser.  This changes the URL in the browser address bar, and the browser then issues an HTTP GET for the new address.  With an HTTP GET, no form/post data are ever sent; all arguments are assumed to be in the URL querystring.

If you'd like to avoid the redirect and use a true rewrite, change your web.config to use `action=rewrite`.  Using this method, no redirect header is sent back to the browser, the browser address bar never changes, and IIS simply redirects the current request stream to a different location.

Something tells me that's not what you want-- you want the address bar in the browser to change and you want the form/post data to be preserved.  This is not possible unless you do something very unusual, e.g. render a temporary interstitial page containing the original form/post request with an action pointing at the new URL.  I don't recommend doing this.

Why not just change the form action in the original page's HTML?

Comment: Thanks! Changing the first two rules (that I did not notice were redirect instead of rewrite) did the trick.